# Github Pages throws 404 error when refreshing app

Tags: angular, routes, http-status-code-404, github-pages

I am trying to host the following on GitHub pages: https://hdz.github.io/FCS-Training/

Whenever I click on a link it works well, but once I refresh I still get a 404 error.

I tried this solution : https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site

I tried the wildcard : `{path: '**', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'}`

I also tried that : `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})`

but neither of them works.

Here's the repo : https://github.com/Hdz/FCS-Training

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong and how could I fix the 404 to redirect to the main page of the website please ?

Comment: Your site is served from `gh-pages` branch. And there is no 404.html page created there

Comment: And you should copy final index.html file to 404.html page https://github.com/Hdz/FCS-Training/blob/gh-pages/index.html

Comment: There's something I don't understand, Travis-ci does deploy the master branch right ? Why is the branch gh-pages used then ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I couldn't solve it for a while, when I refreshed the web being in a component for example "contact" it returned to "home". But not anymore!

I put the ./ to the "base-href" of the "index.html" and the "404.html" and that's it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).